# Making a ring without extra squares

Tags: modeling

So I'm very new to blender and I'm trying to work on learning more complex shapes, and I want to make a ring (like the letter O not like a wedding ring) and I just learned how to make semi circles, and I want to make a full ring. The way I'm doing this now is by making a plane the length of my radius, and slicing off the portion I want to use to make the ring, and using spin to make it circular, so I have it circular but I'm not sure how to do this without the squares I used to get the radius. So either how do I remove these squares, or what is a better way to do this?

Here is a picture showing the leftover squares I'm talking about, thanks for any help[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a circle (make sure fill is set to nothing)

Enter edit mode.

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude. Do not move the mouse and press enter.

Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and move the mouse inwards to set the inner radius.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Much easier than what I was doing